# Conditional Sorting of Data using php codes from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm having problem to sort table values by different categories of books and I'm having 10 categories of books.
Categories are mentioned in a table  entitled "categories" as (1, 2, 3,...10) and each category contains more than 100 books.

I just want to sort books only by one category such as 1 from my database and ignore all the other categories.
I used following php codes but it sorted the results as whole of column "categories" that means all the categories are sorted one by one but
I just want to sort data by single category.

```
 $orderby = "ORDER BY books.category DESC";
$addparam = "";
if ($_GET["incldead"] == 2)
    $wherea[] = "visible = 'yes'";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books $where") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_NUM);
$count = $row[0];
if ($count)
{
  $pager = pager($booksperpage, $count, "browse.php?" . $addparam);
  $query = "SELECT books.id, books.category, books.name, books.times_completed, books.size, books.added, books.type,  books.comments,books.numfiles,books.filename,books.owner,IF(books.nfo <> '', 1, 0) as nfoav," .
  "categories.name AS cat_name, categories.image AS cat_pic, users.username FROM books LEFT JOIN categories ON category = categories.id LEFT JOIN users ON books.owner = users.id $where $orderby {$pager['limit']}";
  $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Output of above code similar to below:

[image: image 1]

My desired output:

[image: image 2]

Please guide me how it'll be possible by amending in above php codes...

Comment: you know you can order by more than just 1 column in mysql right?

Comment: Make order by clause order by category first ,then order by id  `$orderby = "ORDER BY category ASC, books.id DESC";`